# Calling non-DLL function from DLL function

Tags: c++, dll

I am writting a DLL:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
_DLLAPI int __stdcall myDLLFunc()  
{  
    return test(4);
}
int test(int arg)
{
    return arg * arg;
}
```

But when I try to compile it in MS VC++ Express it says:

> error C3861: 'test': identifier not found

How do I call `test` from `myDLLFunc`?
Am I missing the obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the called function ahead of the caller in your code and it should compile.  C++ does not do 'look ahead' for called functions, they must be declared ahead of any usage.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int test(int arg)
{
    return arg * arg;
}_DLLAPI int __stdcall myDLLFunc()  

{  
    return test(4);
}
```

Typically, you would keep the function's declaration separate (in a header file) from the definition (in the code file) to reduce dependency complexity.

Comment: Or you can do forward declaration of test() without moving test() above myDLLFunc().

Comment: @Ganesh - thanks, I added a note about header/code separation